# Check and Uncheck Parent/Child Checkboxes using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have to use group of checkboxes in my project.

This is how my HTML look like:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="mod[6]" value="1">
    </label>
  </td>
  <td><span>Parent Module</span></td>
  <td>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="mod[7]" value="1"> Sub Module
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="mod[8]" value="1"> Sub Module
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="mod[9]" value="1"> Sub Module
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
</table>
```

Using this checkboxes, users can select their preferred parent and sub module selection.
When making that selection, it should work as follows.

- When a parent is checked, all children are checked under it. (Parents
  and children are separated by a row on the table)
- When a parent is unchecked, all children are unchecked under it.
- At the very least, When one child is checked, its parent should be checked.
- When no child is checked, its parents should not be checked.

I have done this work to some extent. But I look forward to your help in completing this.

This is how I tried it using Jquery.

```
$('#myTable').on( "change", "label > input[type=checkbox]", function(e) {
  var checkboxes = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=checkbox]");
  if ($(this).hasClass("parent")) { 
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      checkboxes.prop("checked", true);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Added a "Check All" box in the `<thead>`
Added the third state called `indeterminate` which is applied to a `.parent` or `#all` when ***some*** of their subordinate checkboxes are checked.

Assigned `.child` class to the subordinate checkboxes just to make it a little easier to follow hopefully. Details are commented in the example.

```js
// *️⃣ Code for indeterminate state - There are comments for removal
// Bind all checkboxes to the change event
$(':checkbox').on('change', checkUncheck);

function checkUncheck(e) {
  // The tag the user checked/unchecked
  const $this = $(this);
  // Reference to the closest <tr>
  const $row = $this.closest('tr');
  /*
  If the user clicked a .parent...
  ...and if it is checked...
  ... .find() all the <td> of $row...
  ...and check them all...
  ...otherwise uncheck them all
  */
  if ($this.is('.parent')) {
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
      $row.find('.child').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $row.find('.child').prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
  /*
  If the user checked/unchecked a .child...
  ... .makeArray() of all of $row .child and...
  ... if .every() <td> is .checked then check .parent
  ... and if .some() <td> are .checked then .parent is...
  ... indeterminate, otherwise uncheck .parent
  */
  if ($this.is('.child')) {
    $row.find('.parent').prop('indeterminate', false);  //*️⃣
    const chxArray = jQuery.makeArray($row.find('.child'));
    let rowChecked = chxArray.every(cb => cb.checked);  //*️⃣
    let someChecked = chxArray.some(cb => cb.checked);
    if (rowChecked) {    /* if (someChecked) { */       //*️⃣ 
      $row.find('.parent').prop('checked', true);
    } else if (someChecked) {
      $row.find('.parent').prop('indeterminate', true); //*️⃣
    } else {
      $row.find('.parent').prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
  /*
  If the user clicked #all...
  ...and if it is checked...
  ... .find() all the <td> of $tB...
  ...and check them all...
  ...otherwise uncheck them all
  */
  if ($this.is('#all')) {
      $('.parent').prop('indeterminate', false); //*️⃣
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
      $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
  /*
  If the user checked/unchecked a .child or .parent...
  ... .makeArray() of all of <td> in <tbody> and...
  ... if .every() <td> is checked...
  ... #all is checked and if .some() <td> are checked...
  ... then #all is indeterminate...
  ... otherwise uncheck #all
  */
  let allArray = jQuery.makeArray($(':checkbox').not('#all'));
  if (allArray.every(cb => cb.checked)) { 
    $('#all').prop('indeterminate', false); //*️⃣
    $('#all').prop('checked', true); /* Move to: ✳️ */
  } else if (allArray.some(cb => cb.checked)) {
    $('#all').prop('indeterminate', true);  //*️⃣ ✳️
  } else {
    $('#all').prop('indeterminate', false); //*️⃣
    $('#all').prop('checked', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<table><thead><tr><th><label><input type=checkbox id=all></label><th>All Modules<th><tbody><tr><td><label><input type=checkbox class=parent name=mod[6] value=1></label><td><span>Parent Module</span><td><label><input type=checkbox class=child name=mod[7] value=1> Sub Module</label> <label><input type=checkbox class=child name=mod[8] value=1> Sub Module</label> <label><input type=checkbox class=child name=mod[9] value=1> Sub Module</label><tr><td><label><input type=checkbox class=parent name=mod[6] value=1></label><td><span>Parent Module</span><td><label><input type=checkbox class=child name=mod[7] value=1> Sub Module</label> <label><input type=checkbox class=child name=mod[8] value=1> Sub Module</label> <label><input type=checkbox class=child name=mod[9] value=1> Sub Module</label><tr><td><label><input type=checkbox class=parent name=mod[6] value=1></label><td><span>Parent Module</span><td><label><input type=checkbox class=child name=mod[7] value=1> Sub Module</label> <label><input type=checkbox class=child name=mod[8] value=1> Sub Module</label> <label><input type=checkbox class=child name=mod[9] value=1> Sub Module</label></table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... this is what I wanted. One thing can you tell me how I check/uncheck all the checkboxes in the tbody with one checkbox click in thead.

Comment: @ugsgknt you're welcome. See update.

Comment: Thanks again.. Now its working perfectly... May I know, is there any particular reason to use `indeterminate` instead of `checked`

Comment: When there's a partial amount of `.child` checked in a row `.parent` and `#all` can be `indeterminate` which is a more accurate state than checked or unchecked. I marked the lines with the blue asterisk if you don't want it. Just make sure to change this part `let someChecked = chxArray.some(cb => cb.checked);
    if (`rowChecked`) {` replace "rowChecked" with "someChecked". If this resolved your question, don't forget to click the green checkmark ✅, happy coding.

Comment: Added edit notes should you decide to remove `indeterminate` feature.

Comment: Of course This is resolved my question. Thanks again.

Comment: zer00ne, I come back to this answer and have small thing to figure out with you. The issue is, all these checkboxes load from db, checked checkboxes also save in db. In this case, if parent have childs and user checked a child from it, then its parent is not saving  in db. Let say, one parent have 5 childs and user checked one child and submit the form to save it in db. Then I need to get that child' id only to save in db. Again when I load the checkboxes with the selected checkboxes, I need to check parent checkbox if child is selected when the page is loaded.

Comment: I tried it something like this `$(document).on('change', ':checkbox', checkUncheck).trigger('change');` but it doesn't work for me. Hope you will help me regarding this. Sorry this is wrong the place to ask it, so let me know if I need to ask it as a separate question. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @ugsgknt I think you should start a new question, and reference this question (like a link to https://stackoverflow.com/q/72667982/2813224). You can comment here and add `@zer00ne` and a link to the new question to it so I'll be notified directly.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working demo.
you need to update the code with else condition where you uncheck parents' checkbox
on uncheck child.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myTable').on( "change", "label > input[type=checkbox]", function(e) {
  var checkboxes = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=checkbox]");
  if ($(this).hasClass("parent")) { 
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      checkboxes.prop("checked", true);
    }else
    {
     checkboxes.prop("checked", false);
    }
  }else if($(this).hasClass("child")){
   if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
       $(".parent").prop("checked",true)
    }else
    {
     $(".parent").prop("checked",false)
    }
  } 
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="mod[6]" value="1">
    </label>
  </td>
  <td><span>Parent Module</span></td>
  <td>
    <label>
      <input class="child" type="checkbox" name="mod[7]" value="1"> Sub Module
    </label>
    <label>
      <input class="child" type="checkbox" name="mod[8]" value="1"> Sub Module
    </label>
    <label>
      <input class="child" type="checkbox" name="mod[9]" value="1"> Sub Module
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
<tr>.....</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is a issue in your answer. That is, if I click on child checkbox its unchecking it's parent.